# How to migrate Twilio Python Script to AWS EC2 using Flask

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, flask, twilio

I have built a SMS service (using Twilio) that the user texts to get realtime bus information. At the moment i have been hosting this on my personal computer using ngrok. Now i want to use AWS to host this service, but I am not sure as to how i should go about it. I have tried running a flask webserver and trying to get ngrok to run on AWS, but no luck.

Here is my code concerning Flask and Twilio's REST Api:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/sms", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_monkey():

     resp = MessagingResponse()
     response = request.form['Body']
     if (" " in response):
         response = response.split(" ")

         result =  look_up(response[0], response[1])
     else:
         result =  look_up(response, False)



     resp.message(result)
     return str(resp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a blog post on the Twilio blog on [How to Send SMS Text Messages with AWS Lambda and Python 3.6](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/05/send-sms-text-messages-aws-lambda-python-3-6.html). It does not use Flask, but it can definitely be modified to achieve your goal. Alternatively, you could read about using Flask with AWS Elastic Beanstalk [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html).

Running ngrok on AWS is not the correct approach to this. If you wanted to host your own Flask server, you could use something like [Lightsail](https://amazonlightsail.com/), but that's overkill for this usage.